# utilization of bitmap protocol

Tags: computer-networks, communication-protocols, communication-complexity, protocols, network-analysis

I am curious about utilization calculation in the bitmap protocol. especially if there's a difference between if only station 0 wants to broadcast(and the others doesn't) or only some other station want to broadcast(but the others doesn't)

an example of a problem regarding this: in a bit map protocol with 10 station(numbered 0-9). knowing that the contending time is t and the length of each broadcasting frame is 20t.

a)what is the utilization of the network if all of the stations want to transmit in every time slot?

b)what is the utilization of the network if only station 0 wants to broadcast and the others doesn't?

c)what is the utilization of the network if only station 2 wants to broadcast and the other doesn't?

this is what i tried

a)in the beginning of the contending time, 10 stations want to broadcast so: $\frac{20*10p}{20*10p+1}$

b)$\frac{20*10p(1-p)^9}{20*10p(1-p)^9+1}$

c)$\frac{20*10p((1-p)^9)^3}{20*10p((1-p)^9)^3+1}$

explanation for b and c: only one station wants to broadcast, and in c there are 3 additional points in time we can not broadcast(0,1,2)

i tried looking on this site and on other sites for this topic, but with no luck sadly. there's not much information regarding calculation of utilization of the bitmap protocol, especially single stations in the network.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: @D.W - my problem is with calculating the utilization of a bitmap protocol. i have not found any resource on this site or on other sites that explains how to calculate utilization in the bitmap protocol. my main question is like this, is there a difference whether only station 0 or only station 2 want to broadcast(all of the other don't) - and if so, how could i calculate the utilization? i think it is quite important and there's not a lot of information regarding this protocol sadly. hoping now it makes more sense

Comment: @D.W - the post is better now? did my best to correct it so it could be more beneficial to the community here. really wanting to learn about this

Comment: no one knows this protocol nor can help? :(

Comment: Changing "here's my answer, is it correct?" to "here's what I tried, can you solve this for me?" doesn't really make the question that much better.  This is a very specific exercise, and we're not really looking to be a place where you can paste an exercise and have someone solve it; nor is this question likely to be useful to anyone else in the future.  That's why we'd prefer conceptual questions -- those are more likely to be useful to others in the future.  See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems.